# Logic.class.getResource("effects\\newball.wav"); returns null

Tags: java, file, null

I've got the problem that the following code snip returns null:

```
System.out.println(Logic.class.getResource("effects\\newball.wav"));
```

I have a source folder in my project called effects. in this folder there's the referred file. I think there's a syntax error... Because **THE FILE IS THERE**. I must refer in this way (means with getResource) to my file because I will export it as jar later.

Thank you

Comment: You are so certain that the file exists, you might not realize that the path you specified doesn't.

Comment: Try `/effects/newball.wav`, it must help you.

Comment: It doesn't work. Same problem

Comment: If `effects` itself is a source folder, try just `"/newball.wav"`. Or, check the case of the file; maybe it's `"NewBall.WAV"`?

Comment: @Mansouritta This should work after you export your code to JAR. Also try maybe `Logic.class.getClassLoader().getResource("effects/newball.wav")`

Comment: @Mansouritta So was it the "just 'newball.wav'" part, or the case-part? If the first, according to your comment to JVMATL's answer, effects actually _is_ a subfolder of your source folder... I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @tobias_k There are a lot of posts so I changed my directory structure a lot^^ Sorry for confusing. But now my effects folder is on the same level with the src folder. And when I write /effects, it works. But when I export it as a jar, theres an error that the file can't found. Why is that so?

Comment: You should have it _in_ the `src`. During the build it will be copied to your `bin`. If it's not in the `src` it won't be copied. You should keep it in the `src` if it is to be an embedded-resource

Comment: @Mansouritta Best would be if you include a picture/ascii art of your exact directory structure, including which are source folders, along with your latest code.

Comment: Under JVMATL answer you claimed that path to `effects` is `C:\Users\A723023\RDz\RDz-RZ4\ErstesGutesSpiel\src\effects`. Now you are saying that it is not. Can you [edit] your question and post real info about how your project structure looks like? (You can add links to some outside image hosts, we can later edit into actual image in your post).

Comment: @Pshemo and tobias I dont have enough reputation Point to upload a picture.. But my latest post is actual. Sorry for confusing

Comment: @Mansouritta you can add links that will lead to outside image hosts. We can later put this images in your post for you.

Comment: @Pshemo please upvote this question so OP can update with more info

Comment: Or @tobias_k look at comment ^^

Comment: I cant uploud anything because at the moment am at work and there really strictly security policys... i cant go on a filehostingpage there are many filters

Comment: I think you only need 10 rep points to post images

Comment: @peeskillet Sorry I can't do that. 1) this is really bad question because OP gives misleading informations. 2) because of point 1 I downvoted it already and can't retract it now (will do if OP will correct his question with accurate informations).

Comment: I'm sorry but i can't uploud pictures. The security policys are to strong. They don't let me do that... When I come home, i will completely update my post

Answer (score 2):

Your `effect` directory should be a direct child of the `src` dir. Also in which case, you need a `/` to start the string path. So you would need this

```
System.out.println(Logic.class.getResource("/effects/newball.wav"));

ProjectRoot
          src
             effect
                  newball.wav
```

What I normally do using an IDE is just create a new package and name it whatever I want the file to be - in your case "effect". It's easier that way.

---

**UPDATE**

> *"I did it exatly so, but it still returns null"*

**It works fine for me**

[image]

```
package stackoverflow;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Test.class.getResource("/effects/stack_reverse.png"));

    }
}
```

Output: `file:/C:/Android/workspace/StackOverflow/bin/effects/stack_reverse.png`

Comment: I did it exatly so, but it still returns null

Comment: See my **UPDATE** see if that helps at all

Comment: Thank you! How do you add a picture in a post? That would be helpful for me :)

Comment: You need 10 reputation points. When you post, you will see an image icon above the text area. I'll hook you up with the points to post pictures :)

Comment: Actually, I can't. I just tried. You don't have enough questions for me to up-vote.  You'll get there soon. Also see my comment. My answer is how you should have your file structure. The `effects` should not be outside the `src` if it is to be an embedded resource

Answer (score 0):

Resource paths should use forward slashes, regardless of the filesystem on the machine you are using: try "effects/newball.wav"

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html (Under "resources, Names, and Contexts -- "The name of a resource is independent of the Java implementation; in particular, the path separator is always a slash (/).")

Comment: Any reference about why ``\\`` are bad and `/` good here? From what I heard Java should use both without problems.

Comment: @JVMATL it doesn't work. :( I've tried so much and nothing works

Comment: @Mansouritta - it would help to know the directory layout of your project: where is the effects folder located, relative to the package where logic is located? "Relative" paths are relative to your class path root, not to 'the current directory'. If you update your question to provide this info, people would be able to help you better.

Comment: Thats where the .java files are stored: C:\Users\A723023\RDz\RDz-RZ4\ErstesGutesSpiel\src\mhm

and here are the sounds stored: C:\Users\A723023\RDz\RDz-RZ4\ErstesGutesSpiel\src\effects

Comment: I confess, I'm stumped; it looks like you're doing the right thing, and the answer from @peeskillet, below, looks good to me. Is it possible there's something quirky about how you have defined your classpath? Can you update your question [not in a comment, but in the question above,] to include the class path you are using when executing the program? That might be the missing link.